# Modify array into list

Tags: php, arrays

I need help converting this .csv file:

```
a;a1;1;0;1
b;b1;1;0;0
```

Into this output:

```
a;a1;1;
a;a1;0;
a;a1;1;
b;b1;1;
b;b1;0;
b;b1;0;
```

The output would then be inserted into a specific table in a database. (I have a script for that that works just fine.)

Logic on how it should work:

Count the number of columns (in this case from Column 3 to end of row. There has to be a var that describes from which column to count);

Count number of rows...
Have a foreach loop to explode the data and set it as an array

```
$i=0
foreach($lines as $value) {
$data[$i] = explode(";", $value);
<...>
$i++;
}
```

`count($data);` to get the number of rows

`sizeof($data[0]);` get number of columns

Now due to my lack of php knowledge im kinda stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is, for each line, `array_splice` the 1st two elements, then loop through the remaining elements.

Something like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach($lines as $value) {
    $value = explode(";", $value);

    $first = array_splice($value, 0, 2);

    foreach($value as $x){
        $row = $first;
        $row[] = $x;
        $data[] = implode(';', $row);
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/cckbuu0Y